# Duplicate messages sending in Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: ios, xamarin, firebase-cloud-messaging

In our project we use  Firebase cloud messaging for push notification and we encountered the problem of duplication of messages. Our process looks as follow:

- our client side based on iOS device and we use follow sdk

> Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging 3.1.2
>
> Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.InstanceID 3.2.1
>
> Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Core 5.1.3

- when user login the application request the token
- application send this token to server which is subscribe this token to topic

*Subscribe user for topic reuqest*

```
POST https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:batchAdd
request body   
{
    "to" : "/topics/test",
    "registration_tokens" : ["..user_registration_token.."]
}
```

- server send periodically notifications to the topics

*Send notification for topic subscribers request*

```
POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/our_project_id/messages:send
request body
{
    "message":
    {
        "topic":"test",
        "notification":
        {
            "title":"test-6",
            "body":"test-6"
        }
    }
}
```

- when user logout from application, server perform unsubscribing user token from topics

```
POST https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:batchRemove
{
   "to": "/topics/test",
   "registration_tokens" : ["..user_registration_token.."]
}
```

But, when user login again and request brand new token, device still received push notifications which are sending to the old token, and if we send notifications by the topic such users received **duplicate push notifications**.

If we try get information for old token from api method

```
GET https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/token.....
```

we get response

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>Internal Server Error</TITLE>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
    <H1>Internal Server Error</H1>
    <H2>Error 500</H2>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add ***?details=true*** to your uri.
Be sure to use Authorization key in your header.
Output expected is

> {
> "error": "No information found about this instance id." }

or

```
{
    "application": "com.chrome.windows",
    "subtype": "wp:http://localhost:8089/#xxx-xx-xx-xx-xx-x",
    "scope": "*",
    "authorizedEntity": "xxxx",
    "rel": {
        "topics": {
            }
        }
    },
    "platform": "BROWSER"
}
```